# Google Feed API 'publishedDate' wrong day

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-feed-api

When using Google Feed API JSON result the origin RSS  is being converted a day off in the JSON results.

For example the following origin RSS entry:

```
<pubDate>Mon, 19 Aug 2013 04:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
```

...becomes:

```
"Sun, 18 Aug 2013 21:00:00 -0700"
```

...in the JSON result.  Is there any way to designate a time zone so it knows not to convert?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'wrong day' in your question, both date strings are equivalent, just in different timezones. In your Javascript you can just construct a `Date` object from either one and then use the [`Date` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) like either `toLocaleString` or `toUTCString` to represent it locally however you want it to.

[Here's a sample Fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/T2eXy/).

Comment: Thanks! Using the toUTCString() helped.